# Stop flickering of mouseover on <a> element when changing background color of its parent <td>? jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a table where the user can select elements on the table by clicking, holding the mouse down, and then dragging the mouse over other elements to group select them. The selection is shown to the user by changing the background color of the selected elements to `#444`.

Everything works fine, but in some of the `<td>` elements there lies a child `<a>` element, that when hovered over, changes the background color back to its original background color (white) and then back to the selection color `#444` after the mouse has left the `<a>` back into its parent `<td>`. When this action is performed quickly, it gives off the appearance of a "flickering" effect, which is undesirable to my needs for the application.

I want to prevent the flickering by having my jQuery script ignore the `<a>` element when it is moused over. What is the best approach to doing this?

I have tried using `.not('#parent-body td a)` and `toggleClass('highlight')` with no success and ended up with the same result.

Here is a fiddle I created to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wapLxnb/4/

Comment: Your fiddle code seems to be working fine.

Comment: The fiddle works to demonstrate the problem I am having. When the user clicks and holds down the mouse, and then drags the mouse over the links, the links (when moused over with the left-click held down) cause the `<td>` background colors to revert back to their previous background colors. I want to eliminate that. I want the X's to behave the same way as the A's when moused over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseover` events can occur multiple times, so `mouseenter` is a better option for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5wapLxnb/6/

```
var isMouseDown = false;

$("#parent-body td").on("mousedown", function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    return false;
}).mouseenter(function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    }
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function() {
    isMouseDown = false;                        
});
```